# Apache Configuration: how to limit non-hostname request to some pages?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a virtualhost configuration of my Apache server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/app/www"
    ServerName myhostname
    <Directory "/app/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to allow access only requests with `myhostname` as hostname. But I want to deny all other requests made by hostname or server-ip:

```
http://myhostiname/ ALLOW
http://1.2.3.4/ (this is one of the server ip addresses) DENY
```

My virtualhost configuration works as expected.

Now I have to edit the configuration to let user access one particular path by ip because a client cannot solve the local hostname.

This is an example:

```
http://myhostiname ALLOW
http://1.2.3.4/ DENY
http://1.2.3.4/any/path DENY
http://1.2.3.4/allowed/path ALLOW
http://1.2.3.4/allowed/path/subpath ALLOW
```

I tried the `<Location>` element in a new virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    DocumentRoot "/app/www"
    <Directory "/app/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Location "/">
      AllowOverride None
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
    </Location>
    <Location "^/allowed">
      Allow from all
    </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

But this deny everything but the hostname requests. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split your vhost-configuration into two or more vhosts. It is possible to do it all in one vhost, but I find "separated" configs easier to read and to log.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # default match for port 80
    # matches domain set by ServerName (and possibly other domains unless specified in other vhosts)
    ServerName myhostname
    DocumentRoot "/app/www"

    <Location "/">
        # copied from your example. if not needed, you can remove this <Location/>-block.
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-myhostname.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-myhostname.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    # matches all requests to ip address and port
    DocumentRoot "/app/www"

    # initially: all requests forbidden
    <Location "/">
        # Options and AllowOverride copied from first vhost. remove if not needed.
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Require all denied
    </Location>

    # allow access to everything below "/allowed/path/"
    <Location "/allowed/path/">
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    # use separate logfile
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-1234.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-1234.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
    # default match
    # fallback for any other ports/ip addresses/domains we might have forgotten/misconfigured
    DocumentRoot "/app/www"

    # all requests forbidden
    <Location "/">
        Require all denied
    </Location>

    # again, use separate logfile
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-default.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-default.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```